# How to play the Text behind the SimpleCaptcha Image

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, captcha, java-ee-6

pleasure to be here.

I get a simple question. I am developing an application using simplecaptcha1.2.1.jar (http://simplecaptcha.sourceforge.net/).

Everything is fine, I know how to use SimpleCaptcha API and AudioCaptcha, and I know how to customize creating my our Servlet with AudioCaptcha ac = new AudioCaptcha.Builder() and Captcha captcha = new Captcha.Builder(400, 100).

What I am trying know is to synchronize the text that appears at the Image behind the Simple Captcha, and the audio behind of the AudioCaptcha, basically what you see is what you play and hear.

Any ideas on how to play and hear the text behind the image?

I will be more then grateful.

Best Regards

Marcel Aguiar

Answer (score 0):

for those who did the question that I did using simplecaptcha API 1.2 (how to synchronize the code between Audio and Captcha Image), here follow my conclusion so we can share between us.

Step 1_) The AudioCaptcha original implementation is made to accept just Numbers, so, instead of use DefaultTextProducer, you have to use NumberAnswerProducer

```
TextProducer tp = new NumbersAnswerProducer(4,true);

new AudioCaptcha.Builder()
.addVoice()
.addAnswer(tp)
.build());
```

You can run the test, if you try to pass DefaultTextProducer() to AudioCaptcha builder it will fail.

---

Step 2_) Sharing the same TextProducer for both Captcha and AudioCaptcha

I cloned the project from the GIT Repository from SimpleCaptcha to understand more about "AudioCaptcha.Builder().addAnswer(tp)" and Captcha.Builder(400, 100).addText(tp)

If you try this you will see that , even sharing the same instance of TextProducer tp = new NumbersAnswerProducer(4,true); for both, you will get always (I mean Always trust me), different Code behind the Image and the Audio. 
Why?

Because behind the implementation of .addAnswer(tp) and .addText(tp) the code is calling a method named .getText(), even for the same instance of the TextProducer. And this getText has a random code behind him:

```
public String getText() {
String capText = "";
for (int i = 0; i < _length; i++) {
capText += _srcChars[RAND.nextInt(_srcChars.length)];
}
return capText;
}
```

So, again, even using the same instance of TextProducer, you will have different codes every time you call .addAnswer(tp) and .addText(tp), because behind these guys they will call getText().

Finally, a way that I found to solve that was, I had to create my own implementation of getText() behind TextProducer, to be able to have the same value for both Captcha and AudioCaptcha.

Best Regards